# specify delimiter when using dataframe.ReadCSV in the gota library

Tags: go, gota

I'm trying to figure out how to use `dataframe.LoadOptions` in the [gota library](https://github.com/kniren/gota) to specify a delimiter when reading the CSV file.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/kniren/gota/dataframe"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    content, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/to/csv/file.csv")
    ioContent := strings.NewReader(string(content))

    df := dataframe.ReadCSV(ioContent)

    fmt.Println(df)
}
```

The dataframe.ReadCSV function takes an `options` variable of type *dataframe.LoadOptions

I checked the definition for the dataframe.LoadOptions struct and found the following:

```
type LoadOption func(*loadOptions)

type loadOptions struct {
    defaultType series.Type
    detectTypes bool
    hasHeader bool
    names []string
    nanValues []string
    delimiter rune
    types map[string]series.Type
}
```

I'm new to Go and got stuck on this.  First time I've come across a definition like this: `type LoadOption func(*loadOptions)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library uses [functional options](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis).

dataframe.ReadCSV takes *any number* of dataframe.LoadOption, where LoadOption is a function type. Look through the docs for things that return a value of LoadOption and pass those to ReadCSV:

```
dataframe.ReadCSV(ioContent,
    dataframe.WithDelimiter(';'),
    dataframe.HasHeader(true),
    // etc.
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That makes sense now.